# Ping.SendPingAsync isn’t working as expected for macOS Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I tried to get ping time for a domain using [Ping.SendPingAsync(host, timeOut)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=netframework-4.8) API. It seems like the PingReply.RoundtripTime value is always higher compared to what I observed in the terminal.

To be more precise, for the same domain `google.com`, reply.RoundtripTime is 76 to 78 ms when I called `SendPingAsync` method on macOS, whereas the value is 54 to 56 ms when I send commands to the terminal.

```
Terminal command: Ping google.com
Response: 64 bytes from 74.125.24.113: icmp_seq=156 ttl=104 time=54.082 ms
```

Here is my full test code:

```
private async Task PingAsync()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();

        PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync("google.com", 500);

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to get ping detials");
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have used the same code for my win project (WPF), it works as expected, the response time is quite close to windows API response and terminal ping time.

Can you suggest to me how I could get ping time on my Xamarin.Mac app? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**Platform and version for this application:**

- Xamarin.Mac 6.20.2
- .Net Framework 4.8
- Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.93
- macOS Catalina version 10.15.2

Comment: Do you execute the code in Debug? Debug add additional operation. Try in Release to approach the raw.

Comment: @vernou, I have checked to run this code in Release mode according to your suggestions. It seems to me, the behavior is the same as before.

Comment: I try on Windows with .NET Framework 4.8 console app, it is the same response time between the app and cmd...

Comment: Yeah!! That's the thing I mentioned earlier. The windows project is working fine but the macOS isn't working as expected. The response time between the app and terminal for macOS isn't the same.